# MSSQL connection String:

Tags: sql-server, triggers, connection-string, keda, keda-scaledjob

I'm trying to create scaledobject in keda and I'm referring the official keda documentation for this with MSSQL scaler.

While configuring connectionstring in this format "Server=example.database.windows.net;Port=1433;Database=AdventureWorks;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user1;Password=Password#1;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" , Is the server to be configured is same as hostname?

Basically, whether the host parameter that we specify in connection parameters explicitly is the same as the Server parameter in ADO format: ?

Can someone please help me here? After deploying my scaled object  in keda with MSSQL trigger(I'm considering server name is same as host instance and configured like that) , I'm getting ready and active status as unknown.. In logs I'm only seeing that it's trying to create a HPA and then nothing happens. I guess the operator is getting stuck here. Please guide me on how to proceed to establish connection with MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs you either have to specify the connection string OR host: keda.sh/docs/latest/scalers/mssql